# Receive data packets via BLE Notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, core-bluetooth

When receiving multiple packets via BLE notifications, iOS is only giving me access to the final packet sent. I am using YMSCoreBluetooth to connect to a BLE peripheral with multiple services, each of which has multiple characteristics. I connect to the peripheral, discover the services and discover the characteristics of those services without a problem. My goal is to subscribe to a certain characteristic's notifications and receive via the notifications a series of data packets. My subscription is successful and I can see through use of NSLogs within my code that I am receiving the notifications containing the data. The issue is that when I go to access the data from each notification as it comes in, every notification gives me only the data contained in the last packet sent.

My code for receiving notifications is as follows:

```
- (void)notifyCharacteristicHandler:(YMSCBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Error in handling notification.\n%@", error);
    }
    else if ([characteristic.name isEqualToString:@"InterestingChar"]) {
        if (self.firstNotify) {
            self.mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            self.firstNotify = NO;
        }
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];
        data = characteristic.cbCharacteristic.value;

        [self.mutableData appendData:data];

        self.notifyCounter++;
        NSLog(@"Notify received! Count: %ld \nData =%@",(long)self.notifyCounter,self.mutableData);
    }
    else NSLog(@"Other notification received");
}
```

For instance, if I receive 5 notifications with the following data:

1 ababababab

2 bcbcbcbcbc

3 cdcdcdcdcd

4 dedededede

5 efefefefef

My NSLog would print out efefefefef for the first notify data, efefefefef efefefefef for the second, and so on appending the last data value for each subsequent notify.

I am trying to send the notifications as quickly as possible from the peripheral using BLE. The connection interval is between 20ms and 40ms (iOS demands a range of at least 20ms) and three packets are being sent per connection interval.

EDIT:

Paulw11's suggestion worked beautifully. I fixed the issue by amending the YMSCB 'didUpdateValueForCharacteristic' method to obtain the value of the characteristic and pass it along with the pointer to the characteristic itself onto the 'notifyCharacteristicHandler' method. The amended method now looks as follows:

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {
    __weak YMSCBPeripheral *this = self;
    NSData *value = characteristic.value;
    _YMS_PERFORM_ON_MAIN_THREAD(^{
        YMSCBService *btService = [this findService:characteristic.service];
        YMSCBCharacteristic *yc = [btService findCharacteristic:characteristic];

        if (yc.cbCharacteristic.isNotifying) {
            [btService notifyCharacteristicHandler:yc value:value error:error];

        } else {
            if ([yc.readCallbacks count] > 0) {
                [yc executeReadCallback:characteristic.value error:error];
            }
        }

        if ([this.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:)]) {
            [this.delegate peripheral:peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:characteristic error:error];
        }
    });
}
```

You obviously also need to amend the 'notifyCharacteristicHandler' method to accept the new argument.

Comment: The alloc/init of `NSData` is useless since you do data = `characteristic.cbCharacteristic.value`. Plus shouldn't it be without the "characeteristic.value"? Typo error?

Comment: It's a YMSCBCharacteristic, which has a CBCharacteristic as a property, which in turn has a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the internal `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` delegate method of the YMSCoreBluetooth library, it sends the data to your method using a "perform on main thread" and it doesn't capture the data - it just sends a reference to the characteristic.  Also, it performs a "findCharacteristic" on the characteristic by executing a linear search through the array on the main thread even though this could have been done immediately on entering the delegate method on the current thread.  Granted this isn't going to be a very big array but it seems that this library hasn't been created with performance in mind.

I suspect that you have a timing problem - by the time your method executes the data in the characteristic has been over written. If you have control over your peripheral, slow it right down for a test to see if the problem goes away.

If it is timing related then you could try a straight Core-Bluetooth implementation, or try a modification to YMSCoreBluetooth so that it captures the data earlier - perhaps if it created a copy of the peripheral at the start of `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic` and sent that to your method it would work.

Comment: You're exactly right. After posting, I slowed down my peripheral notifications just as you suggest here and the data started coming through as expected at pretty low speeds. I've been looking through YMS for an explanation, but hadn't found what you did yet. Thank you! I'll edit the original post when I figure out which fix I need for posterity.